# Is covariance matrix Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C$ be a variance-covariance matrix of variables *x*, *y*, and *z*:

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}cov(x,x)&cov(x,y)&cov(x,z)\\cov(y,x)&cov(y,y)&cov(y,z)\\cov(z,x)&cov(z,y)&cov(z,z)\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $M$ be any matrix (not necessarily $C$ as defined as above). I want to raise a matrix $M$ to a negative half power to make $M^{-1/2}$. However, I am aware that I cannot simply take inverse and square root of $M$ if $M$ is Hermitian; I have to perform diagonalization into $O$$D$$O^{-1}$, where $O$ is a matrix of eigenvectors and D is a matrix of eigenvalues.

So my question is, is $C$ Hermitian? Ultimately, I want to raise $C$to a negative half power.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are. In fact since we usually only talk about real-valued random variables, the covariances are actually all real numbers. So covariance matrices are actually real symmetric (which makes them Hermitian automatically of course).

And they're much more than just Hermitian: all covariance matrices are *positive semi-definite* (PSD) which is perhaps their most important property! To see why, note that if we have a random vector $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)^T$ then their covariance matrix $C:=(\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j))_{ij}$ can be rewritten as
$$C=\Bbb E((\mathbf{X}-\Bbb E(\mathbf{X}))(\mathbf{X}-\Bbb E(\mathbf{X}))^T)$$
whose validity I leave to you as an exercise:) and from here you can promptly see that $C$ is PSD (hint: use the definition).

Comment: great, thank you so much. Could you please vote my question? lol